# Which is more efficient: assigning every time or checking?

Tags: for-loop, rust, variable-assignment

Say that you have a variable `ididit: mut bool` which controls whether or not something has been done, and a loop in which that thing may be done. For visualization purposes, here's some example code:

```
let mut ididit: bool = false;

for i in 0..SomeArbitraryValue {
    // do stuff
    if (conditions) {  // While certainly possible, this probably won't run every iteration.
        ididit = true;
    }
}
```

With that in mind, would it be more efficient to check whether or not `ididit` is already true before assigning?

In other words, which is more efficient: checking for redundancy or just assigning every time?

Comment: Checking first can only be slower than not checking first, but when compiling with optimization there likely isn't any difference.

Comment: In general, the way to answer performance questions is to measure.

Comment: In your exemple, the best is to break loop after assignation `ididit = true; break;` we not need to continue checking other condition. If the assignation is a clone form a big struct it will be better to checking before.

Comment: Like all performance-related questions, it depends. If `conditions` are expensive to check (and if you don't do anything else in the `if`), then checking `ididit` first may improve speed (e.g. `if (!ididit) && conditions {…}`). Otherwise not checking is probably faster, but the difference will probably be too small to measure.

Comment: Just to check if I correctly understand the question: you are comparing the code from the question, `if conditions { ididit = true; }`, with something like `if conditions { if !ididit { ididit = true; } }`. Or are you comparing it with  `if !ididit { if conditions { ididit = true; } }`? I believe the first and the second variants are about equally efficient, with the possibility that the second one is slightly slower (but they might compile to the same machine code due to optimizer magic). The third variant could be more efficient if `conditions` are expensive to compute.

Comment: @user4815162342 The first variant (check conditions, then assign if (and only if) it isn't already true).

Comment: @Zeppi There's other stuff happening in the loop which I didn't include here for purposes of brevity. `ididit` acts as a switch for whether or not something occurs within each loop iteration.

Comment: @Jmb Thanks. Would you mind putting it in an answer?

Comment: There is a relevant topic about the question on the Rust internals forum: https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/optimizing-branched-assignings-based-on-possible-states/13812

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So much depends on the context. For your trivial example, Sven is correct in saying that it likely gets optimized to an assignment. But if it doesn't, you are costing an extra memory cycle for the check. And even if it does get optimized out, it still adds code complexity that has to be maintained. If you are dealing with more complex entities it can be quite different.

Consider a case where reading a value is delayed while other processing is going on, e.g. a web access that is synchronous because the value is usually needed to continue, and writes just get put in a queue while execution continues. Now the checking gets expensive and it is better to write without checking.

Now consider the situation where writing to an object makes it "dirty" and forces other processing. An example is having the value tied to a displayed object. Assigning to that value gets quite expensive since it involves a display update while reading it does not. The display update is asynchronous so it may not be noticed using metrics but it can affect the application as a whole. So in this case checking could be much better. This is one situation where it takes some real thought.

Most of the time you can know which is better by thinking it through while taking the context into account. But if you have to run metrics to determine which is which, it usually ends up being so little difference as not to matter enough to incur the code complexity cost. You can end up over-optimizing your app into an unmaintainable mess.